# After Restore Log_reuse_wait_desc of Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, restore

I'm wondering if anybody has ran into this issue before and has any suggestions on what's causing it/how to fix it.  We are restoring a database into lower Dev environments and after the restore the *log_reuse_wait_desc* is *Replication*.  The problem is we are not using keep replication or CDCs.

This happens in a couple of different setups but I'll keep this initial one simple.

Database from a 2008 instance restored to a 2012 instance.  Only way to clear it out is to create a test publication on any random table, no subscription needed, and *log_reuse_wait* clears.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this following script on your database?

```
use master
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = N'your db name', @optname = N'<<name of your 
publication>>', @value = N'false'
GO

select name, is_published, is_subscribed, is_merge_published, is_distributor
from sys.databases where name =<<your database name>>
```

This might be due to orphaned replication metadata. You can use the below query to remove:

```
USE master
EXEC sp_removedbreplication
    @dbname = 'myDB'
```

Comment: Replaced the @optname with publish and ran it.  Got the following message but Wait_Desc is still replication.

"The replication option 'publish' of database 'DBName' has been set to false."

Comment: `name is_published is_subscribed is_merge_published is_distributor


DBName 0 0 0 0`

Comment: Tried that along with sp_replflush and still no luck.

Comment: Do you have CDC enabled on the database?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try running below command to see if that fixes the issue.

```
EXEC sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_sgno = NULL, @numtrans = 0, @time = 0, @reset = 1;
```

If not, I will create a publication for a single article and then run the above command again. This should mark all the replication transactions as complete. Once I am able to shrink the log file, I'll remove my publication.